# Regex match inside html tag (not capture, just match)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

This is the string: `<sup>test</sup>`
And the regex I use: `(\([\w+\-*\/]+?\)|(?!<)\w+(?<!>))`

Why it matches all the `sup`, `test`, and `sup` ?
I think I've used the negative lookahead of < and negative lookbehind of >, so I think it won't catch sup since before it there is '<', and after it there is '>'

What I want is just to match only 'test', **NOT match the whole thing and capture 'test'**.

Please help

Comment: In PHP, what you want to do, with a regex, is easily done with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - `<[^<>]+>(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+`. Also, you seem to have swapped a lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: use xml/html parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming content is between `>` and `<` You can simply use this regex : `(?<=>)[^<]+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKXgpm/2)

**Explanation**

`[^<]+` Any character except a `<`

`(?<=>)` Precedeed by a `>`

> **Note**
>
> If you don't want to match new line or carriage return, use this one `(?<=>)[^<\r\n]+` instead. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/kKXgpm/3) is a demo.

Keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the content between the <.+?> content

`<sup>test</sup>`

regex: <.+?>(.+?)</.+?>

depending on how precise you want to look you have to tweak the search pattern, but this is up to your own logic